# Не собирается проект GUI в Lazaus на Linux Mint. Говорит, что нет unit db, а он есть

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

Установил Lazarus на Linux Mint. Создал проект для создания графического приложения на Free Pascal. При сборке проекта появляется ошибка:
"fcllaz.pas(11,3) Fatal: Невозможно найти db, используемый в fcllaz пакета FCL" 
Как можно исправить данную ошибку?

Comment: Версия Lazarus? Версия Linux Mint?

Comment: Lazarus 2.0.6, Linux Mint 20.3